# Python: Efficient way to do a CPU heavy task while multiplexing io sensor data?

Tags: python, io, css-selectors, cpu, multiplexing

Using python for a little while but I'm getting out of my realm of understanding with this one. Most tutorials and questions regarding sockets and selectors are all echo or chat server related; I've found little on my situation.

I have numerous sensors that will connect via UDP. Each sensor outputs data at different rates; all of which are much faster than 1 second. I want to create a program that will read in the sensor data and run a CPU heavy task using that data. The task will take longer than the update rate of the sensors.

Currently, I am looking at asyncio or selectors. Using selectors, I have managed to get the incoming sensor data to be read in a non-blocking manner. My problem currently, is that the UDP buffer is first-in, first-out (FIFO) and when the task takes a long time, the sensor data is no longer in sync - the fastest sensor ends up coming in to the program much slower.

I haven't been able to find a way to make the UDP LIFO or empty the buffer. I have read that one method is to close the socket, but I am struggling with that as it is all tied up with the selector. Any ideas?

Also, if anyone has a better methodology to the way I am going about this, I welcome your input? I have been fumbling about with this for some days.

Lastly, what are the 'callback' bits in the while True loop all about?

```
import selectors
import socket
import time

sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()

def get_data(sock, mask):
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    data_decoded = data.decode().rstrip()
    print(f'from {addr} we get {data_decoded}')
    close_socket(sock)


def get_connection(name, host, port):
    print(f'starting up {name} on {host} port {port}')
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.setblocking(False)
    sock.bind((host, port))
    return sock

def close_socket(sock):
    print(f'{sock} closing')
    sock.close()

def do_work():
    #work happens
    time.sleep(2)

sensor1 = get_connection('sensor1', 'localhost', 5000)
sensor2 = get_connection('sensor2', 'localhost', 6000)
sel.register(sensor1, selectors.EVENT_READ, get_data)
sel.register(sensor2, selectors.EVENT_READ, get_data)  

while True:

    for key, mask in sel.select(timeout=0):
        callback = key.data
        callback(key.fileobj, mask)

    do_work()
```

Answer (score 0):

## Creates a FIFO queue

```
from collections import deque
x = collections.deque(maxlen=3)
x.append(new_input)
```

and

## Removes the newest entry (LIFO)

```
x.pop()
```